# Zip library for Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, zip

I'm downloading zip files and place them in isolated storage on Windows Phone 7. Is there an API or library that allows me to unzip the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SharpZipLib](http://slsharpziplib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/75509) to decompress downloaded zip files. I have used this version (binaries downloaded from Codeplex) in my applications without any issues, however, I would recommend download the source and compiling it yourself. The decompressed file can be read into a string -

```
// check for magic numbers
if (data.Length > 2 && (data[0] == 31 && data[1] == 139))
{
   using (var ms = new MemoryStream(data))
   using (var gzip = new GZipInputStream(ms))
   using (var reader = new StreamReader(gzip))
   {
      fileContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
   }
}
```

data is an array of bytes which holds the zip file read from IsolatedStorage. fileContents is a string that holds the contents of the decompressed file.

HTH,
indyfromoz

Comment: I'm also looking for a gzip library, and though sharpziplib seems perfect, its GPL so can't be used for commercial apps, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @tempy - The license is actually [GNU with an exception](http://slsharpziplib.codeplex.com/discussions/85286) that allows inclusion in a commercial application _if_ the binary (as opposed to the source) is used.

Answer (score 1):

SharpZipLib is under GNU license and is therefore not allowed by the Microsoft app store.

Comment: As mentioned above, the license is granted with an exception that allows distribution of the _binary_ in commercial applications.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following small library useful for unzipping files on WP7:
[REALLY small unzip utility for Silverlight – Part 2](http://www.sharpgis.net/www.sharpgis.net/post/2010/08/25/REALLY-small-unzip-utility-for-Silverlight-e28093-Part-2.aspx)