# Unzip files from isolated storage on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, compression, zip

I'm working on an app that downloads zip files and stores them in IsolatedStorage and at some point will need to unzip them, but I'm not seeing any support for Zip files.  Any Ideas?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007758/ziplibrary-for-windows-phone-7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either of the following libraries to unzip files on WP7:

- [SharpZipLib for Silverlight 3/4 and WP7](http://slsharpziplib.codeplex.com/)
- [REALLY small unzip utility for Silverlight – Part 2](http://www.sharpgis.net/www.sharpgis.net/post/2010/08/25/REALLY-small-unzip-utility-for-Silverlight-e28093-Part-2.aspx)

Comment: Note SharpZip licensing is GPL.

Comment: @MickN you've got a crucial point there. That is, it's not quite suitable for commercial software.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it natively if you know the file structure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5794609/155892