# extract zip file from isolated storage to a folder wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am developing a windows 8 phone application and i want to extract a zip file present in the isolated storage to a specific folder in the isolated storage itself. 
How can i do this ? I know there is a  SharpzipLibrary for this purpose , but the samples sshows extract a zip file from remote server to isolated storage. In my case the zip file is in the isolated storage only .
Is there any examples to show how to extract local isolated storage zip file ?

Answer (score 0):

Go through this link

it Explains the procedure for Windows Phone 7

Should be the same. Give it a try and leave a Reply.

[Extracting Zip in Windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785717/how-do-i-extract-zip-file-in-windows-phone-7)

I Just hope it does not use a url rather isolated storage. may be file system URl might do. Please take a look

Comment: its reading stream (data ) from remote url, in my case the data (zip file) is in isolated storage only. SO i guess what i want to do is to convert the local file to a stream , then i guess i can use the code in the above link

Comment: yes :) Best would be you get the stream and place it exactly from the spot it starts reading the stream. Remove the other code above it :)